# Find all elements in vector and delete them

Tags: c++, stdvector

I have some vector temp = {1,2,2,3,4}. How to find all elem = 2, save there positions in another vector and delete from the first one.

```
vector<int> another
vector<int>::iterator it;
for (it = temp.begin(); it != temp.end(); ) 
{
   if (it == elem) {   //?
       another.push_back(it);   //?
       temp.erase(it++);
   }
   else 
   {
       ++it;
   }
}
```

Comment: first indent your code

Comment: Doesn't compile either.

Comment: What do you mean by _save there positions_? After removal, the positions will be invalid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To save the positions:

```
#include <iterator>

for (auto it = temp.begin(); it != temp.end(); ++it)
    if (*it == 2)
        another.push_back(std::distance(temp.begin(), it));
```

To erase:

```
#include <algorithm>

temp.erase(std::remove(temp.begin(), temp.end(), 2), temp.end());
```

This works for a larger class of containers than just vectors, thanks to the genericity of iterators.

Answer (score 3):

```
std::remove(vec.begin(), vec.end(), 2);
```

this should do the trick.

(Of course, to actually erase them from the vector, you have to write

```
vec.erase(std::remove(vec.begin(), vec.end(), 2), vec.end());
```

according to the [erase-remove idiom](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Erase-remove_idiom).)

**Edit:** Just noticed:

> save there positions in another vector

("with guns in *there* hands", right?) - basically that doesn't make a lot of sense, the positions will be invalidated when you remove the elements from the container...

Comment: You'd want to save their positions in another vector though

Comment: @Magtheridon96 Then `std::remove_if()` and the predicate should take care of that.

Comment: You next have to erase the elements from the container. Following the [Erase-remove-ideom](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Erase-remove_idiom)

Comment: @andre Perhaps that wasn't entirely clear to OP indeed. I'm updating my question, thanks for the remark.